# WinXp SP3, my network connectivity command lines doesnt' work

Tags: windows-xp, networking, command-line

So I really don't get it what happened.
 My network diagnostic command line tools **'are not recognized as a batch file or external command'** in command line ( ping, netstat, trcrt...). Files are in Windows XP default folder and in Enviroment Variables path also.
But I can do with normal GUI everything. I didn't use command line network diagnostic on this computer for week or more, the only unusual thing is that I installed a couple of new IDE-s to my machine ( Netbeans Ide,Eclipse Juno, ActivePython, IntelliJ Idea and Lazarus). I also have Virtualbox installed more than one month or so.

Is there any chance that Virtualbox network adapters have some conflict with my command line tools ? 
Or there is something else ?

OS is Windows XP SP3

Comment: Have you tried changing to the directory the EXEs are in and running them? If they work fine, can you type `set` at the command prompt and copy-paste your complete `path` here?

Comment: I second Karan's suggestion.   If you go to c:\Windows\System32 and type commands like ping, tracert it should work.   Also, if the poster could show us what his $PATH variable was set to that would be helpful.

Comment: I tried ping and traceroute in command line from default directory  **"C:\windows\system32** "and commands do work. But I have strange problem with PATH variables, is it possible that some application delete particular PATH variable after I restart computer ? Path variables: **C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;**

Comment: path set to `C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32` should not cause problems. Still, try setting it to `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts` instead and see if that helps. Also, next time you receive the error, type set *in that very command prompt window* and check whether the path variable has been changed to something else.